# How to keep only the website name in the address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, oop

I am looking for a way of only displaying the website name in the address bar..such as www.whatever.com no matter what page you are on. This website is php, html, css. The website has thousands of pages. Any help. I have tried many of the .htaccess methods posted on Stackoverflow and I just cannot seem to find what I need. Sometimes I get 500 or other errors.
Plus I am only asking since I changing from procedural code to OOP. In procedural code I use a iframe, but does not work in OOP.

Comment: only js without using `#` might be hard and confusing for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to achieve that except using iframe which is not an seo friendly solution. But if your website is for internal use only iframe is the easiest solution.